# Keras multithreading and load_model

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I'm experiencing some issues with a multithreaded application that uses Keras with Tensorflow backend.

I have 2 threads:

- Thread A: Creates a model once and compiles it. Every 30 minutes it fetches a new version of the train data and trains the model once again. The it saves the model to an .h5 file
- Thread B: Using thread-locks (to make multithreading safe), this thread preprocesses its data and  calls load_model on the aforementioned .h5 file.
  After that it calls a predict on the loaded model.

I'm puzzled, because I keep getting an Exception like the one below:

```
Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 60, 17), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph
```

when `load_model()` is called.
I have found this https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6124 , but since on Thread A I'm not making any predictions, I'm calling `_make_predict_function()` after I fit the model on Thread A and then saving the model.

Do you have any suggestions/tips?

Comment: Any example code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099745/keras-error-when-predicting-on-multithreading on how to achieve this correctly.